# How do I convert the elements of nested lists into separate lists?

Tags: python, list

Say I have a list of lists;

```
my_list = [['apple', 'banana', 'orange'], ['carrot', 'pumpkin', 'potato']]
```

Is there a way that I can convert each element in each separate list into its own list?

Output:

```
new_list = [[['apple'], ['banana'], ['orange']], [['carrot'], ['pumpkin'], ['potato']]]
```

Comment: Does `[[[x] for x in y] for y in my_list]` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a list comprehension to wrap each string in its own list:

```py
[[[item] for item in sublist] for sublist in my_list]
```

This outputs:

```py
[[['apple'], ['banana'], ['orange']], [['carrot'], ['pumpkin'], ['potato']]]
```